# MongoDB not reflecting written entries from Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express, socket.io

I am implementing a MongoStore for use in session storage within my Node.js/Express application, however  it looks as if none of the sessions are actually being stored in the database. (The MongoDB does not even have the db.session).

Socket.io 'authorization' takes the incoming data, and crosschecks the sent sessionID, however it keeps returning empty.

Hope someone could shed some light on any issues?

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var utils = require("express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils");
var parseSignedCookie = utils.parseSignedCookie;
var cookie = require('cookie');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(cookieParser());

var sessionStore = new MongoStore({
        db: 'express',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27018,  
        collection: 'session', 
        auto_reconnect:true
});

app.use(session({
    cookie: { maxAge: 5000 } ,
    secret: "session secret",
    store: sessionStore
}));


function checkSession(req,res,next){
    if(req.session.user){
        next();
    }
    else {
        req.session.error = "Get Outta here!";
        res.redirect('/');
    }
}


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('./index.html');
});

app.post('/',function(req,res){
    if(req.body.name){
        req.session.user=req.body.name;
        res.redirect('/info');
    }
    else {
        req.session.error = "Auth Failure";
        res.redirect('back');
    }
});

app.get('/info', checkSession, function(req,res){
    if(req.headers.cookie){
        var session_id = utils.parseSignedCookie(req.headers.cookie, 'session secret');
        console.log(session_id);


        console.log("true");
        res.sendfile('./info.html');
    }
    else {
        console.log("false");
        res.redirect('/');
    }


});

var http = require('http').Server(app);
http.listen(80, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:80');
});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using your `sessionStore` anywhere. Try this:

```
app.use(session({
  store: sessionStore,
  cookie: { maxAge: 5000 } ,
  secret: "session secret" 
}));
```

Comment: Good catch, I had forgotten to include this line in the question code. I actually still have the same error with the addition though.